# How to refer to my object from template in Angular?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I have project with array of notifications. I add them to template using *ngFor. How can I pass some data about current notification from template to delete it from array?

My project.ts

```
  public notifications: Notification[] = [...someData];

  clearOne() {
    ...should delete from array
  }
```

My project.html

```
<div *ngFor="let n of notifications">
  <div (click)="clearOne">{{ n }}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div *ngFor="let n of notifications">
  <div (click)="clearOne(n)">{{ n }}</div>
</div>
```

In your component.ts

```
clearOne(notification) {
  // Remove from array
  let index = this.notifications.indexOf(notification);
  this.notifications.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Comment: really, the problem was with clearOne() method, but not with passing object. It works now!